# fabricjs How to fix wrong position when create group with mask

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I create new group use two objects. But positon of group not show as I wanted. This is my code:

```js
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  cropFace();
});

var canvas_face = new fabric.Canvas('canvas_face');

canvas_face.setWidth(800);
canvas_face.setHeight(600);

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/fFMMxXF.jpg', function (img) {
    img1 = img;
    fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/J1JQ6BK.jpg', function (img) {
        //img1.scaleToWidth(canvas_face.getWidth());
        img2 = img;
        //img2.scaleToHeight(300);
        img2.left = 50;
        img2.top = 50;
        img2.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
        canvas_face.add(img1);
        img1.center();
        img2.scaleToWidth(800 / 2);
        img2.scaleToHeight(600 / 2);
        canvas_face.add(img2);
        img2.center();
    });
});

function cropFace() {
 var group = new fabric.Group([canvas_face.item(0), canvas_face.item(1)], {
     left: canvas_face.item(0).left,
     top: canvas_face.item(0).top,
     width: canvas_face.item(0).width,
     height: canvas_face.item(0).height
     });

    canvas_face.clear().renderAll();
    canvas_face.add(group);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <canvas id="canvas_face"></canvas>
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

Input:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWmqy.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjCDk.jpg

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWllU.jpg

I'm newbie . Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: can you make a fiddle/snippet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/20vg8erq/3/
Can you help me fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to scale img2's size to be the same as img1:
https://jsfiddle.net/yaLs09z7/

```
//* Instead of: */
//img2.scaleToWidth(800 / 2);
//img2.scaleToHeight(600 / 2);

// Try:
img2.scaleToWidth(img1.getOriginalSize().width);
img2.scaleToHeight(img1.getOriginalSize().height);
```